# Finding html source code between two html tag using java

Tags: java, android

**Finding html elements by id**

In my project i want to something like this example

```
<html>
<body>
<table >
<tr>
    <td>first column<br></td>

     <td>second column</td>
     <td>third column</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the html source code between `<tr></tr>` tag.
output:

```
<td>first column</td>
<td>second column</td>
<td>third column </td>
```

I am successfully done find value of tag but in my project i want html source code.
I am use htmlcleaner library for finding value.
Is there any library available or method in htmlcleaner?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Jericho HTML Parser: http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use jQuery to search the source then manipulate or display the tag, id, class, or attribute. If I wasn't on a cell phone I would give syntax but I'll  edit later. One example...

api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: sorry,I want to do in core java without using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java HTML Parser

http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

HTML Parser is a Java library used to parse HTML in either a linear or nested fashion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use split method to

initially `originalString` is the original `String`

```
 String strAfterFirstTrTag = originalString.split("<tr>");
  String[] partsAfterTrTag =  strAfterFirstTrTag.split("</tr>");
  String HtmlSource = partsAfterTrTag[0];
  //use HtmlSource

  originalString = partsAfterTrTag[1];
  strAfterFirstTrTag = null;
  partsAfterTrTag  = null;
  HtmlSource = null;
```

you can loop in this code to to find sequential tags..

Comment: how to finding each <tr> in my document ?